# Does Firebase functions retain state for google assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

The scenario is this. I want to show the user one or two items, but I don't want to keep showing the same items over and over again. I don't think `Firebase` functions will retain state because each function call will activate the function again. So how do I maintain state without having to store it in the database.

Answer (score 4):

No, Firebase Functions don't retain state. In fact, you're not even guaranteed to be running on the same server in between calls to the same webhook.

If you want to maintain the state *during* the conversation, but between different parts of the conversation, you have two good ways to do it:

1. If you're using the actions-on-google JavaScript library, you can put data into the `app.data` field and it will be available in the same place in the next call. (I can't find documentation on this, but its reported in https://plus.google.com/105458329026934344336/posts/Xr1KPiMPzpH)
2. Since you're using Dialogflow, you can add the state as parameters to a Context. These parameters will remain in the Context, and available to future Intents that expect it as an incoming Context, as long as the Context is active.

If you need to maintain state *between* conversations, you will need to save that state, probably associated with the anonymous UserID that is passed to you with each request.

These methods are similar to what you have when you're working with web requests for a user.

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and get back to you with the results

Comment: Hopefully it helps! If it does - an upvote and/or accepting the answer is always appreciated. If you have specific detailed questions as you try to implement it, posting a new StackOverflow question with code that you've tried and what isn't working is usually the best way we can help you further.